# Why is Parallel.ForEach loop only doing a shallow copy?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have the following code:

```
List<List<Material>> materialCombos;
Parallel.ForEach(materialCombos, combination =>
{
   Material material1 = combination[0];
   Material material2 = combination[1];                                              
   double[] tempValues1 =
        material1.MaterialImages
                 .OrderBy(mi => mi.Time)
                 .Select(mi => Convert.ToDouble(mi.Temperature))
                 .ToArray();
});


public class Material
{
        [Key]
        public int MaterialID { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Name of the material.
        /// </summary>
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // other accessors here...

        /// <summary>
        /// Collection of apparent temperature images with meta-data for this material.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual ICollection<MaterialImage> MaterialImages { get; set; }
}
```

It works perfectly fine when using the synchronous foreach loop. However, when I use the parallel version (as above), the `MaterialImages` object doesn't always copy across to the `combination` object and when viewing it in the debugger it is  null and therefore an exception is thrown in the anonymous function.

Any ideas why this is happening, is it because when it iterates through materialCombos and gets each combination out it does a shallow copy?

Comment: There is no shallow copying of items going on when iterating through the list. I quess your problem comes from a incomplete input set, that is: one or more of the combinations has 0 or 1 materials. Why dont you use a tuple or keyvaluepair instead of a list for the variations?

Comment: Yes - you're right re tuple/keyvaluepair would improve the code. However, that is not the problem, in the debugger the materailCombos object has a perfect set of pairs with all members correctly populated. When you debug into the anonymous method, the MaterialImages member becomes null and it happens on the second or third iteration through.

Comment: I.e. if you hover over the `combination` object and look at `combination[1].MaterialImages` it may be null. I say 'may' because it doesn't happen on the first iteration.

Comment: `MaterialImages` is a virtual property that isn't shown here. Odds are there is something in there that isn't thread-safe. There's probably a race condition somewhere in your code, but not in the code that you've posted thus far.

Comment: The `Material` object is a model object used with entity framework representing the Material table.

Comment: MaterialImages is virtual for EF.

Comment: @Gabe - Oh so maybe MaterialImages hasn't been loaded up yet via EF?

Answer (score 2):

Your original post left out the fact that you're using objects from the EF object context. Since that's not thread-safe, you can't do what you want in parallel. It may work to retrieve all the objects and *then* operate on them concurrently, but I'm not an expert in EF.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using a thread safe collection.  Switch your type to a `ConcurrentBag<ConcurrentBag<Material>>` for starters.  Also, doesnt look like you are showing what you are doing with the array within the loop (the snippet of code is incomplete)....if you are expecting to access anything you build up within the loop *outside* of the parralel loop, you will need to make sure that it is also using a thread safe implementation.

What you are probably seeing in the debugger is non-deterministic behaviour due to the threading.

Comment: Collections shouldn't really require synchronizing read access. (Of course it could be written to somewhere outside the posted excerpt.)

Comment: Its an incomplete code snippet, suggestion was based on assumption that something else is being done that we aren't seeing above...  :)

Comment: I only do read operations on `List<List<Material>>`. I do not mutate it.